# C# Adding a comma at the end of each line after reading the file with StreamReader

Tags: c#, formatting

I'm using `StramReader` to read a `.txt` file and using the `string.Replace` to do some formatting.

So far the output in to the `Rixhtextbox` is what I want, but now I need to add a comma at the end of every line. what would be the best way to accomplish this?

```
using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(fileStream))
{
     var fileContent = string.empty;                   
     fileContent = reader.ReadToEnd();
     richTextBox2.Text = fileContent;

     // message to tell user that the file was loaded successfully
     MessageBox.Show(" File Loaded Succesfully");

     // file formatting
     var format1 = fileContent.Replace("     08    ", ",8,");
     var format2 = format1.Replace("     07    ", ",7,");
     var formatF = format2.Remove(0,62);
     string formatF = format9.Replace("    ", " ");

     richTextBox1.Text = formatF;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the file you're working with has newline characters (\r\n or \n), you could do a string.Replace to prepend the newline with a comma, i.e.

```
string.Replace(Environment.NewLine, $",{Environment.NewLine}");
```

or if you're using C# 5 or below:

```
string.Replace(Environment.NewLine, "," + Environment.NewLine);
```